# IEnumerator: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#

Code:

```
public List<Interfaces.Test> IJ_;
IEnumerator<Interfaces.Test> Ij_ = Objects.GetEnumerator();
int count = IJ_.Count;
Ij_.MoveNext();
for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
{
    if (x >= count)
        break;
    Test MyBase = IJ_.Current;
    if (MyBase == null)
        obj_.MoveNext(); //here the error
}
```

Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
```

Please help me.

Comment: As the error says, the collection was modified. Are you modifying that list either on another thread, or during the loop (e.g. by adding or removing elements)?

Comment: If another thread modifies collection, simply lock that collection.

Comment: I downvoted this because the formatting is poor, the code is piecemealed together instead of clearly showing what's going on, and the problem is a simple issue that the error message tells you.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but your `for` statement could easily be replaced with a much more readable `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, the collection is modified during the iteration, which is an illegal operation.

Either way, the right way to iterate using an enumerator is this:

```
var Ij_ = Objects.GetEnumerator();

while (Ij.MoveNext())
{
    Test MyBase = IJ_.Current;

    // I understood that you want to skip null elements, so...
    if (MyBase == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    // ...
}
```

You should make sure that you don't add, remove or set items in the collection during the iteration (not in the loop, and not in a different thread). Changing an element's inner state is allowed.

If the enumerator is your implementation, and the error still occurs after assuring that the collection is not modified during the iteration, it might be helpful to post the enumerator's code as well.

Comment: Enumerators should be disposed, but anyway why he can't simply use a `foreach`? (i.e. `foreach (Test myBase in Objects) { ... })`

Comment: @PaoloMoretti I just assumed that he can't, for some weird reason. Of course that a foreach is the best.

Answer (score 1):

lock the collection when enum or make change to the collection.

Comment: Yorye Nathan Thank you, I will test it.

Comment: var Ij_ = Objects.GetEnumerator();

while (Ij.MoveNext())//Error here
{
    Test MyBase = IJ_.Current;

    // I understood that you want to skip null elements, so...
    if (MyBase == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    // ...
}